# gropuby and remove specified groups in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'B':['c','t','k','c','c','k']})
```

I need to group df by A and remove A groups where B ='t'. What is pandas `groupby` syntax to do this? In my example answer are A groups 2 and 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `groupby/filter` would work here (filter only return groups that meet a certain condition). So, for example, you could do the following:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: (x['B'] != 't').all())

   A  B
2  2  k
3  2  c
4  3  c
5  3  k
```

`(x['B'] != 't').all()`  allows us to only keep a group if there are no rows with a 't' in column B

Or you could write the filter the following way: Create a booleen series based on whether an row of column B are 't'. If you sum the booleen Series, the sum will be greater than zero if any of the elements were 't':

```
>>> df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: (x['B'] == 't').sum() == 0)

   A  B
2  2  k
3  2  c
4  3  c
5  3  k
```

There are other ways to write the filter condition but they all have this same flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
In [3]: df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: ~(x['B']=='t').any())
Out[3]: 
   A  B
2  2  k
3  2  c
4  3  c
5  3  k
```